# HTML adding user info to div with ajax and MYSQL + PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I am trying to have 2 separate divs with one labeled Email and the 2nd div named Number. When a user chooses a person from drop down the retrieved info from PHP + MySQL should be added in a div just how it gets added to the div when you click add at: http://jsfiddle.net/QVUHU/84/

I am stuck because I dont know how to add the retrieved info into 2 divs one for email one for number like the one at js fiddle...

Below is my html + ajax and PHP code

HTML + AJAX

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Achau</option>
<option value="2">Ravi</option>
<option value="3">Justin</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />


<div id="txtHint">
<b><table>
<tr>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Number</th>

</tr></b></div>



</body>
</html>
```

PHP + MySQL

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect("tghbdfg1","Userbhgins","Jpgbhfw3");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("UserLogins", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM PersonInfo WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo " <br />";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['PNumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP file should return JSON or XML so you can easily separate it into email and number. Also, your current HTML output is not valid because it contains `b` and `br` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<th>Email: <div id="email"></div></th>
<th>Number: <div id="number"></div></th>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById["email"].innerHTML = "Hello";
document.getElementById["number"].innerHTML = "World";
```

**EDIT:**

No need to return html tags in your respnse. There are better ways to do this(JSON response) but this is simplest solution:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Email'] . "|" . $row['PNumber'];
  }
```

Javascript:

Replace

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

With:

```
var emailPhoneArray = xmlhttp.responseText.split("|");

if(emailPhoneArray != null && emailPhoneArray.length() == 2) {
    document.getElementById["email"].innerHTML = emailPhoneArray[0];
    document.getElementById["number"].innerHTML = emailPhoneArray[1];
}
else {
    alert("Wrong response!");
}
```

Comment: what you are saying does work but how can I split the email and number?